# Windows Phone 8 Application Bar Button Long Tap Event

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am working on a windows phone 8 c# application. I have to get long tap events of Forward and Backward buttons that I have placed in the Application bar, but found only Click event for application bar button.

**Please let me know how to capture the long tap event for an application bar button?**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You will probably end up creating your own control for this. App bar buttons are not standard Silverlight controls. However, I wouldn't add long tab on a appbar button. It is just not a standard app behavior in windows phone and your users aren't going to be comfortable with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. The ApplicationBar API is quite restrictive, which is a deliberate move by Microsoft to ensure consistency. You cannot handle arbitrary events from the ApplicationBar. If you want this kind of behaviour, you will have to build your own UI to support it.

It is worth noting that your users will not expect 'long press' (more commonly referred to as tap-and-hold) behaviour on the app-bar.

Comment: Thank you. Let me know is there is any toolkits code samples for creating a custom application bar

Comment: yes i will let you know if i find anything regarding this             if you think it is correct you can tick it as correct ...