# Dynamically adding buttons to Application Bar in Windows Phone 8 & MVVM

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-8

I have a ViewModel in my application

```
/// <summary>
/// The sample view model
/// </summary>
public class SampleViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    public SampleViewModel(IApplicationBarService applicationBarService)
    {
      this.applicationBarService = applicationBarService
      this.ApplicationBarService.AddButton("Add Bookmark", new Uri("Images/favs-toadd.png", UriKind.Relative), this.OnAddPnrBookmark);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the application bar service.
    /// </summary>
    public IApplicationBarService ApplicationBarService { get; set; }   }
```

The implementation of IApplicationBarService looks like this

```
/// <summary>
/// The application service.
/// </summary>
public class ApplicationBarService : IApplicationBarService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the application bar.
    /// </summary>
    public IApplicationBar ApplicationBar
    {
        get
        {
            var currentPage = ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Content as MainPage;
            if (currentPage != null && currentPage.ApplicationBar == null)
            {
                currentPage.ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
            }

            if (currentPage != null)
            {
                return currentPage.ApplicationBar;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The add button.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="title">
    /// The title.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="imageUrl">
    /// The image url.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="onClick">
    /// The on click.
    /// </param>
    public void AddButton(string title, Uri imageUrl, Action onClick)
    {
        var newButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton()
        {
            Text = title,
            IconUri = imageUrl,
        };
        newButton.Click += (sender, e) => onClick.Invoke();
        this.ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(newButton);
    }
```

}

I am injecting the application bar into the view model and the sample view model resides in a portable library while the application bar service implementation is native to phone.

When i run the app the code fails at

var currentPage = ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Content as MainPage;

as RootVisual is null and hence I am unable add buttons via
this.ApplicationBarService.AddMethod

My guess is this has to do something with the Page not being loaded as the same code works if i intialize the application Bar using a RelayCommand bound to a button on the page.

I have seen some other threads([Windows Phone 8 Application Bar Button Long Tap Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700362/windows-phone-8-application-bar-button-long-tap-event))
 where the PhoneApplicationPage's ApplicationBar property is bound to the ViewModel, but i cannot implement that as my view model resides in the portable class library.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you simply wait for the page to load?

Comment: Yeah Toni ultimately thats what i did, see the answer below and validate

Comment: Seems i cant post an answer until tomorrow hence using comments, I came up with this solution using the Interactivity library, i added an event trigger and bound it to a command on my view model where i added the app bar buttons, which solved the issue

Comment: Great, please post that answer tomorrow so that other people can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding an Event Trigger for the Loaded event

```
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SampleViewModel.InitAppBar}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

SampleViewModel.InitAppBar contains the code to add buttons dynamically, this time around reference to ApplicationBar is not null and the code works